# iPhone - creating core data structures on OSX and populate them

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

OK, I know how to use core data and I know how to populate them from code on Xcode, but how do you guys manage to replicate the same structure on OSX and populate the tables, exporting the final sqlite file to Xcode?

What I mean is this: I want a way to see the same core data structures on OSX and have the ability to populate them with records from comma delimited files, for example, create all the modifications I need and then exporting the sqlite file and the xcdatamodeld file structure to Xcode.

And yes, I know a bunch of apps that enable me to read sqlite files and edit them, but this is not the same thing.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is. That is what I have already done. Just make sure you share the same ManagedObjectModel between these two apps. Than you can use your Mac App to populate the database, although I know that CoreData is not a database.

So create a usual CoreData App on the mac or iPhone and make sure you share the same ManagedObjectModel, so copy the file into the app. Then copy the database file from one app to the other and make sure Xcode includes them in the build process.